# the view size gets smaller when the view is rotated

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a view. when it's rotated, the view size gets smaller.  would you please take a look at the pics that I've attached?

[image: before rotating]

[image: after rotating]

[image: it should be this size]

```
@IBAction func buttonForNewView(_ sender: Any) {
    self.view.addSubview(customvView)
    customvView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    customvView.backgroundColor = .gray
    customvView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    customvView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: view.frame.size.height*0.1).isActive = true
    customvView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: view.frame.size.width*0.1).isActive = true
    customvView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -view.frame.size.width*0.1).isActive = true
    customvView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant:-view.frame.size.height*0.1).isActive = true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constraints are not recalculated when the device is rotated.
This breaks out the constraint calculation into a separate function.  Then it overrides traitCollectionDidChange(). When the trait collection changes, it removes the old constraints (to prevent auto layout from getting confused) and reapplies new constraints.

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var customvView: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        customvView = UIView()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func constrainCustomvView() {
        customvView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: view.frame.size.height*0.1).isActive = true
        customvView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: view.frame.size.width*0.1).isActive = true
        customvView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -view.frame.size.width*0.1).isActive = true
        customvView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant:-view.frame.size.height*0.1).isActive = true
    }

    override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        if view.subviews.contains(customvView) { // for the case that the traits change before the view is created

            // remove the existing constraits, or autolayout will have to choose between two and it will choose poorly
            for constraint in view.constraints {
                if let first = constraint.firstItem as? UIView, first == customvView {
                    view.removeConstraint(constraint)
                }
                
                if let second = constraint.secondItem as? UIView, second == customvView {
                    view.removeConstraint(constraint)
                }
            }
            constrainCustomvView()
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func CustomButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.view.addSubview(customvView)
        customvView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        customvView.backgroundColor = .gray
        customvView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        constrainCustomvView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this code.

```
    let val = view.frame.size.height*0.1

    self.view.addSubview(customvView)
    customvView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    customvView.backgroundColor = .gray
    customvView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    customvView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: val).isActive = true
    customvView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: val).isActive = true
    customvView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -val).isActive = true
    customvView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant:-val).isActive = true
```